# jQuery text highlight within HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, livesearch

I have a text field where the user can search for the name of places. How can I highlight the text on result **excluding** what the user had entered that appears on the result? Following is my code in jQuery:

```
<input maxlength="64" id="war_desc" name="searchtext" size="20" class="form200" autocomplete="off" value="">

<div class="auto-complete autocomplete_choices" data-component-bound="true" style="top: 352px; left: 352.5px; width: 172px; display: none;">
<ul>
        <!-- Search result will be append here by html() -->
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#war_desc').keyup(function(e){
    var search_place = $(this).val();
    if(search_place == ''){
        $('.autocomplete_choices').hide();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url:'".$baseUrl."business/searchnew"."',
            data:{'search_place':$(this).val()},
            dataType:'json',
            Type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){

                var listHtml = '';
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                listHtml += '<li class="item" data-display-value="Shoe Exchange" title=Shoe Exchange>'+data[i]['business_name']+'</li>';
            }
                $('.autocomplete_choices').show();
                $('.autocomplete_choices ul').html(listHtml);
            }
        });
    }
})
</script>
```

Following is an image that describe my problems:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: See this for answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14164015/1920232

Comment: OP wants to do the inverse of that answer

Comment: @peterm this is inverse buddy

Comment: But actually that only takes a tiny bit of fiddling. http://jsfiddle.net/RTn3h/2/

Comment: Don't use single quote to set values of your attribute. It should be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer here that peterm found

[Simple Text Highlight with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163817/simple-text-highlight-with-jquery/14164015#14164015)

Change the last line from

```
$(this).html(text.replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords.join('|') + ")" , 'gi'), "<b>$1</b>"));
```

to

```
$(this).html('<b>' + text.replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords.join('|') + ")" , 'gi'), "</b>$1<b>")) + '</b>';
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTn3h/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple string replace method

```
var str = "Hello zlippr";
str = "Hello"+str.replace(str,"<b>"+str+"</b>").replace("Hello","")
document.writeln(str)
```

Your code will be like this

```
data[i]['business_name'] = $(this).val()+data[i]['business_name'].replace(data[i]['business_name'],"<b>"+data[i]['business_name']+"</b>").replace($(this).val(),"")
'<li class="item" data-display-value="Shoe Exchange" title=Shoe Exchange>'+data[i]['business_name']+'</li>';
```

Comment: how does i can use it with my code above? Look at listHtml +=