# Search specific word in text and add class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i have a text like this:

```
<p>Hi this is a text and i wan't to add a class to some words which are here</p>
```

And I wan't to add class ".red" to this words: "some","here","add", for example.
How can I make this with jQuery?
The easier the code the best it is.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery

Comment: that's uses js, not jquery, and I can't understand that code, i just want a simple solution like this, i'm not sure but i think it can be done with "find()"

Comment: You can't use `.find()` to access anything other than elements, and individual words aren't elements. jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167855/highlight-text-inside-html-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
$("p").each().function(){
    $this=$(this);
    if($this.html().indexOf("some") > -1)
        $this.addClass("red");
}
```