# jQuery clone node error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have to check if a 'p' element contains some text, if so create another element 'span' then clone the 'p' element and append and replace it to the 'span' element. However i got the following error:

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The
>   new child element is null.

Here is my codes:

```
if ($("p:contains('computer forensics is')")) {
            var highlight = document.createElement('span');
            highlight.className = 'highlight';
            highlight.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            highlight.id = "";
            highlight.setAttribute("title", "");
            var node = $("p:contains('computer forensics is')");
            var wordClone = node.clone(true);
            highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, node);
        }
```

Comment: Consider using mixture of jQuery and pure JavaScript methods correctly.

Comment: As `VisioN` suggests, if you are going to use jQuery at all, might as well use it for everything that it supports. jQuery code is generally smaller (and more cross-browser compatible) than raw JavaScript.

Comment: Just use jQuery for everything and lose a fair amount of code line. And if you want to use both for jquery node prefix a $ that way it's easy to track jquery instance over normal nodes.

Comment: Also, your `if` clause doesn't make sense, as check for element existence should be done with `$(...).length > 0` condition.

Comment: Note your code is still broken as `if ($("p:contains('computer forensics is')"))` always returns truthy. You meant `if ($("p:contains('computer forensics is')").length)`

Comment: A JSFiddle would have been ideal for this question. It has several problems and could do with a complete jQuery re-write :)

Comment: Can you please describe what this code is supposed to do as it really looks like it is doing something either very odd, or just unnecessary?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie when a 'p' element contains the following text 'computer foren...', a span element needs to be created and entered like that: <span class="" style="background-color"><p>Computer forencics is</p></span>

I know there are other methods like:
$("p:contains('computer forensics is')").css("background-color","red") but i want to stick to create a span and append the p element to it

Comment: I am pretty sure `span`s are not meant to contain `p`aragraphs in valid HTML. A `span` is just a sequential run of characters you need to style *within a paragraph or div*.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie yeah you are right

Comment: Have added a new answer based on all the comments and suggestions that should do what you want, rather than what you asked :) Note: Your text matching is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot everyone and @TrueBlueAussie
Actually i modified your answer as in jsfiddle to get the expected results. The problem was that the i needed to highlight some texts on the html page (converted from docx), i have used a plugin but the highlight part breaks when the text inside 'p' element contains bold or italics text, that why i needed help to find a new way to highlight the text. The plugin i have used was: [link](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)

Answer (score 3):

Make this line:

```
var wordClone = node.clone(true);
```

into this:

```
var wordClone = node.clone(true)[0]; // now it is HTMLElement
```

You were mixing jQuery objects with native elements.

Also I'm at a loss of words why you would ***not*** use jQuery when it is available.

You can rewrite most of the things in jQuery:

```
if ($("p:contains('computer forensics is')").length) {
    var highlight = $('<span/>', {
        "class": "higlight",
        style: "background-color:red;"
    });
    var node = $("p:contains('computer forensics is')");
    var wordClone = node.clone(true);
    highlight.append(wordClone);
    node[0].parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, node);
}
```

Comment: The problem now: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of undefined

Thanks for your help @Amit

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yeah! Updated

Comment: Have you noticed the original code appears to be doing something very odd with the parents and children? It looks backwards. Really needs a JSFiddle :)

Comment: bad luck not working, actually there's no error but still it does not append the span element @Amit

Comment: @ronish, see the comment above your comment

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yeah! But why do you think, this decade is for retirement of first gen programmers? `:)`

Comment: Guess you should have tried it in a fiddle. `css` does not have an `=` in it :> (should be `background-color: red`)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie ah! yeah, I missed out on CSS syntax!

Comment: Hey, you got 2 up-votes on non-working code... (Yours: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Kw3tj/4/) so you are doing OK :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I don't know what was OP's intention and I didn't know the HTML. I just cleaned up his code. BTW, how would I be doing OK?

Comment: "Doing OK" to get two upvotes when the code does not work. I often don't even get that for correct answers :) Suggest you start with the fiddle of your code and work out why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have paragraphs in spans (invalid HTML()), but assuming you want spans in your paragraphs instead:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Kw3tj/2/

```
$(function () {
    var $node = $("p:contains('computer forensics is')");
    if ($node.length) {
        var $highlight = $('<span/>', {
            "class": "highlight", 
            style: "background-color: red"
        });
        $highlight.html($node.html());
        $node.empty().append($highlight);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Note: the code below does not work if the text to target has portions wrapped in other HTML elements like:

 `computer <i>forensics</i> is`**</sup>

All you need is to highlight some specific text portions?
Create your own micro-plugin:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/witol/1/edit)**

```
$.fn.highlight = function(word){
  return this.each(function(){
    var span = $('<span />', {
      'class' : "",
      'html'  : word,
      'id'    : "",
      'title' : "",
      'style' : "color:white; background:red"
    }),
        $el = $(this),
        reg = new RegExp(word, 'ig');
    $el.html($el.html().replace(reg, span.prop('outerHTML')));
  });
};

// ///////
// USE EXAMPLE:

$('p').highlight('computer forensics is');
```

[image]

Comment: thanks you, i did quite the same but the problem now is that the highlight breaks when the text contains some bold or italic char. For example: `<p>That's why computer <i>forensics</i> is awesome` , **computer forensics is** does not get highlighed

Comment: @ronish than your problem is a bit bigger than you might think... There's other answers here on SO related to properly highlight text containing inner elements.