# Highlighting Text on a Web Page

Tags: javascript, highlight

I have a page where I need to highlight some annotations.

Annotations Returned by Service : "Golf", "Cricket", "Ice Hockey"

Content :
 `Peter likes to play Golf, Cricket and < b >Ice < /b > Hockey`

So I used this script from this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/Q8WS5/)

```
$('p').highlight(['Golf','Cricket','Ice Hockey']);
```

This works fine till another sub tag () is encountered in between. Golf and Cricket will get Highlighted but Ice Hockey will not be highlighted. Is there a way I can make Ice Hockey also get highlighted ignoring the html tags ?

Comment: It is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8WS5/555/

Comment: can you show us a demo ? where its not working with `ice hockey`?

Comment: OP is referring to "ice" being enclosed in a B tag(bold) <b> ice </b> hockey

Comment: Checkout this SO Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167855/highlight-text-inside-html-with-jquery

Comment: Bingo !! http://jsfiddle.net/UPs3V/ works. Thanks a lot ZARk !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UPs3V/ is working as expected. The only problem is that it highlights the first occurrence of the text.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8WS5/560/

The issue is that jQuery is calling the library three times once for the `<p>` until `<strong>` once, for the word in bold, and once again for the end.

So that library will have to go, you'll have to rewrite another one.
you'll need to use .text()  that returns text without html .

```
$('span').text().indexOf("Ice Hockey"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So I used the fiddle you shared. Content : <p>Let's test <b>highlight</b> function</p> | Highlight Terms : $('p').highlight(['highlight function']); | The text, 'Highlight Function' failed to highlight as is required. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't make a full functional fiddle. Just added a couple of console.log to show you why it wouldn't work.
Check out my comment on your question, with a SO link to more answers.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/UPs3V worked well although looks like it highlights the first instance only. Looking at the code and trying to iterate. Else it works the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try alternative way..

**HTML**

```
<p>Peter likes to play Golf, Cricket and <b>Ice </b> Hockey <p>
```

**javascript**

```
$('p').highlight(['Golf','Cricket','Ice','Hockey']);
```

Is this acceptable..

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/next2u/Q8WS5/562/)

Comment: Actually no. We will get the terms as "Ice Hockey" together else the script will start highlighting all occurrences of Ice and Hockey as well.